# Background Events via JSON

Tags: fullcalendar

How do I indicate an event as being a background event within a JSON feed (which I'm creating through AJAX).  It is being rendered as a regular event, not a Background event.

JSON Feed:

```
[{"id":"availableForMeeting","start":"2015-02-04T09:00:00","end":"2015-02-04T20:00:00","rendering":"background","overlap":true},{"title":"Working","start":"2015-02-04T10:00:00","end":"2015-02-04T12:00:00","allDay":false,"overlap":true},{"title":"Lunch","start":"2015-02-04T12:00:00","end":"2015-02-04T14:00:00","allDay":false},{"title":"Working","start":"2015-02-04T14:00:00","end":"2015-02-04T19:00:00","allDay":false}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in FullCalendar 2.2+ using **Background Events** by adding `rendering: 'background'` to the event ([documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/)). In the example below, it'd be the same for the JSON feed.

Since you stated you are indeed using `rendering: 'background'`, I would check that

1) You are using the correct version of FullCalendar

2) There are no errors on the page

3) If neither 1 or 2, post a code snippet that shows your problem, since the one below works fine:

Also note that per the docs:

> Background events that are **timed** will only be rendered on the time
>   slots in agenda view. Background events that are **all-day** will only be
>   rendered in month view or the all-day slots of agenda view.

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
      events: [{
        title: 'Main Event',
        start:  moment().add(3, 'h'),
        end: moment().add(5, 'h'),
        color:'#ff0000',
        allDay: false
      }, {
        start:  moment().add(1, 'h'),
        end: moment().add(10, 'h'),
        rendering: 'background'
      }, {
        title: 'Other Event',
        start:  moment().add(6, 'h'),
        end: moment().add(8, 'h'),
        color:'#00cc00',
        allDay: false
      }],
      header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next',
        right: ''
      },
      timezone:'local',
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCal"></div>
```